# How to pass and get POST param in AngularJs-$route before routechange?

Tags: angularjs, post, route-provider

hai currently i am passing ticket id from home page and based on ticket id getting and  resolve the data before route change, this works fine, but my requirement i should not  send ticketid in url(for security problem), how can i achieve this? is there any way to send as a post param??
Thanks in Advance
    current code sample

```
<a href="#/viewticket/?ticketid={{ ID }}">open ticket</a>


when('/viewticket/', {
        templateUrl: 'myurl/url',
        controller: 'mycontroller',
        controllerAs: 'mynewcontroller',
        resolve:{

        ticketdata: function($route,FactoryService)
            {

        return FactoryService.servicemethod().querymethod({'ID' : $route.current.params.ticketid}).$promise.then(function(data){
        return data;
            },function(error){
            console.log("failed route");
            return error;
            });
            }


        }
    })
```

Comment: Viewing profile by id seems good for me, why is it security problem? There is No POST method in client side routing, so you cant. There will be dirty solutions for example saving id in local storage or something like that.

Comment: hai  karaxuna, first thank you for you reply, what i have posted is samle question, we have different scenario, there we cant send id in url.so angular not supporting client side POST :( :(. is encrypt url is good solution?

Comment: Please explain what you mean by security problem. Is only the owner of the profile allowed to view the profile?

Comment: @  Wayne Ellery, @ karaxuna actually we are handling ticket not profile, i have edited my question

Comment: You can get current logged in user on back end (api), can't you? So you can check whether current user has permission to view ticket or not and return 403 status code if user is not allowed. Security must be built on back end, not on front end. Anybody can debug client side script and see ticket url anyway even if you are not showing in url

Comment: i can do this, but need to call one more REST to get the ticket group info, isn't good to call one more service na. so now i have two choice only right. one is local storage and authenticate user.. ?? what about url encryption. is that secure enough???